# Google Maps, MongoDb, NodeJs y Handlebars: GeoJSON

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, google-maps, mongoose, google-api

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en `NodeJS`.

En mi aplicación estoy incorporando un mapa de `Google Maps` y quiero que las coordenadas que tengo en `Mongo`, me los muestre ya [georeferenciadas](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georreferenciaci%C3%B3n) con un [`marker`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/marker).

He estado leyendo que con [`Mongoose GeoJSON`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/geojson.html), pero veo que en el `Schema` pide esto:

```
const citySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      name: String,
      location: {
          type: {
              type: String, // Don't do `{ location: { type: String } }`
              enum: ['Point'], // 'location.type' must be 'Point'
              required: true
          },
          coordinates: {
              type: [Number],
              required: true
           }
       }
});
```

Y yo en mi `Schema` pido latitud y longitud por separado:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const PlatanoSchema = new Schema({
    nombre: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    latitud: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    longitud: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    fecha: {
        type: Date,
        required: true
    },
    produccion:{
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    frutoTon:{
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    casTon:{
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    pinTon:{
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    recPor:{
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    recTon:{
        type: Number,
        required: true
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Platano', PlatanoSchema);
```

Mi pregunta es: ¿Si paso los parámetros de `lat` y `long` en el corchete de coordenadas algo así:

```
const citySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    location: {
        type: {
            type: String, // Don't do `{ location: { type: String } }`
            enum: ['Point'], // 'location.type' must be 'Point'
            required: true
        },
        coordinates: {
            type: [**latitud, longitud**],
            required: true
        }
    }
});
```

O no se como quedaría.